# Yii2 Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST

Tags: yii2

Yii2 delete confirm dialog is not working via menu widget item.

```
[
    'label' => '<i class="fa fa-trash-o alis"></i> Sil',
    'url' => ['site/delete', 'id' => $model->id],
    'linkOptions' => [
        'data-confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
        'data-method' => 'post',
    ],
    'visible' => 'visible'
],
```

And I see this error:

> Method Not Allowed (#405)
>   Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST.

How can I use delete confirm dialog. Then I try this but not working...

```
[
    'label' => '<i class="fa fa-trash-o alis"></i> delete',
    'url' => ['site/delete','id' => $model->id],
    [
        'data' =>[
            'data-confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
            'data-method' => 'post',
        ],
    ],
    'visible' => 'visible'
],
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed problem via template options such as following code block:

```
['label' => '<i class="fa fa-trash-o alis"></i> delete',
    'url' => ['site/delete','id' => $model->id],
    'template' => '<a href="{url}" data-confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this item?", data-method="post">{label}</a>',
    'visible' => 'visible'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

in view file

```
['label' => '<i class="fa fa-trash-o alis"></i> delete',
   'url' => ['site/delete','id' => $model->id],
    'template' => '<a href="{url}" data-confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this item?", data-method="post">{label}</a>',
   'visible' => 'visible'
```

],

and also in AppAsset file we must active depends array like this:

```
public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You send and GET. But in the controller by default for delete - only POST
send POST or edit rules in contoller, like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'], //delete this string to may GET
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of the error is the HTTP method when you click link difference with method you config for the action in function behaviors() of controller. So you need defined the method for the link (sorry my English is not good). I tryed and it worked:

```
Html::a('', $url,
  [
     'data' => [
         'method' => 'post',
          // use it if you want to confirm the action
          'confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
      ],
      'class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn btn-default btn-xs custom_button'
   ]
 );
```